# How to display searchbox on scroll of Grid in UWP same as Whatsapp in iOS?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I want to display SearchBox when the user scrolls Grid similar to the searchbox that appears in Whatsapp when the user scrolls the listView. I know how to add a simple search box that is visible always but is it possible in UWP to have the same behavior as iOS?

[image]

Comment: Can you be more clear. Maybe upload a gif of the required action?

Comment: in iOS Whatsapp App, these search box appears when we scroll the List of chats, I want to add similar behavior. SearchBox should be hidden by default then when user scroll, then the search box should appear.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is by having a ScrollViewers ViewChanged event handler check the type of scrolling. This ScrollViewer can be a part of ListView, GridView etc.

```
private double previousScrollPosition = -1;

private async void ScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ScrollViewer Scroller = sender as ScrollViewer;

        var verticalOffsetValue = Scroller.VerticalOffset;
        var maxVerticalOffsetValue = Scroller.ExtentHeight - Scroller.ViewportHeight;
        if (previousScrollPosition < Scroller.VerticalOffset)
        {
            await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
             () =>
             {
                 previousScrollPosition = Scroller.VerticalOffset;
                 SearchSP.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
             });
        }
        else if (previousScrollPosition > Scroller.VerticalOffset + 70 || Scroller.VerticalOffset == 0)
        {
            await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
             () =>
             {
                 previousScrollPosition = Scroller.VerticalOffset;
                 SearchSP.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
             });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Error in scrollviewer changed " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This below line of code is when if I'm scrolling a small amount of vertical distance ie;70 then don't show the SearchBox but if the change is greater than the offset + 70 then show the SearchBox. Also show it if the scrollviewer is at the top.

```
previousScrollPosition > Scroller.VerticalOffset + 70 || Scroller.VerticalOffset == 0
```

And since you only want the SearchBox when you are on the very top. replace the above line of code by only `Scroller.VerticalOffset == 0`

Comment: Thanks. This works as expected but can you explain what is usage of `var maxVerticalOffsetValue = Scroller.ExtentHeight - Scroller.ViewportHeight;` and `previousScrollPosition > Scroller.VerticalOffset + 70 || Scroller.VerticalOffset == 0`

Comment: Also, searchbox appears when I vertical scroll from bottom to up, is it possible that  it appears when we do gesture similar to pull to refresh?

Comment: Ok will try. Did you understand my point when I said search box should display when gesture similar to pull to refresh is perfomed?

Comment: If you are looking for the exact gesture the try [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1044631/Pull-to-refresh-on-a-Windows-UWP) out. and in the EventHandler make the searchbox visible.

Comment: Ok. I want this `If the user pulls down then they see the search bar.` Your code works fine when I scroll up and then again down.

Comment: Try playing around with offset values. You will have to check at which values do you want to trigger the change and based on that you can add the if conditions accordingly.

Comment: I tried this but event is not called when user pulls down the scroll viewer, when I scroll vertically then only event is called.